# Redirecting stdout to stdin of another program

Tags: c++, c, unix, pipeline, piping

I've gone through a vast quantity of Google links and questions on here in order to understand how pipping works but I can't seem to grasp the concept of making my stdout redirect to the stdin of my second program.

I am attempting to create a program that moves around characters of text, encrypts it and puts it into a string. My second program is supposed to take that string and decrypt it. I understand the functions that are needed to create a pipe but what I don't understand is how it is pointed to the next program, all the source code that I have looked at seems to have both the parent and child in it and not in a second program.

Comment: Show us SOME code...

Comment: Stack Overflow is [a Q&A resource, not a help forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92115/228805). It's for specific questions about coding that can have definite correct answers, not a place to ask open-ended questions seeking broad overviews, tutorials, introductory info, or general pointers about getting started. Please read the [Tour] page and the following advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)].

Comment: Is that necessary to use two different programs for this task? If I understand correct its easily can be implemented in one executable.

Comment: Which language are you using, C or C++?  For example, the C language does not have `std::string` nor `std::istream`.

Comment: Are you looking to share data between two programs?  Are you have one program launch another and share between the two?

Comment: Your implementation will be easier if you store the output from the first program into a file.  The file can then be opened by the second program.  No need for piping.

Comment: Sorry if this was the inappropriate place for this question. I am using c++ and am trying to share data between the two programs. I chose to do it this way so I can get a better understanding of piping.

Answer (score 2):

Establishing a pipe between two programs' standard streams is a matter of how you start the programs.  If one execs the other (`fork()`/`execlp()`, for example), then the parent creates the pipe with `pipe()`, and parent and child use `dup2()` to associate the pipe ends with the appropriate file descriptors (before performing the exec, in the child's case).

If neither program starts the other, then the program that *does* start them (normally a shell) must set up the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the shell in a unix based operating system the pipe `|` character is used to create this link. For example: I want to run program1 and redirect the standard output of program1 to program2 as its standard input.

`program1 | program2`

here is a linux example of getting the names of the directory contents using `ls`  then piping that to `head -3` to get the names of first three files. Then we pipe the three names to `tail -1` to get the last one (or the name of the third file in the directory).

`ls | head -3 | tail -1`